# .Net release mode "file or assembly not found"

Tags: .net, release-mode, debug-mode

Have a strange problem in my application.

This is a prism application with couple of modules in separate projects. Those modules are not referenced directly, they are only copied in "Modules" directory. There is also some base functionality in one more project "Common" - this is referenced by the application and all modules.

Now the problem: if I build the app in debug mode, then everything is OK. But if I build it in release mode - I am getting an error trying to start it "file or assembly Common, Version x.x.x.x or one of its dependencies not found". The important thing is, that this version number x.x.x.x is the number of the in debug mode compiled assembly...

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Comment: How do you deploy your application?

Comment: I just build it and start the exe

Comment: Well, not so strange, there's no lack of self-inflicted pain here.  Pretty easy to forget to re-enter the Post-build event that copies these files for the Release configuration.  And the CLR will have a hard time finding those assemblies so easy to fumble the .config file you need.  Use Fuslogvw.exe if that doesn't help.

Comment: there is no post build event, for them is the "Modules" directory configured as output path, I have checked all of them...
and the DLL where it fails is the directly referenced DLL :(

Comment: tryed the Fuslogvw tool - it sais the binding fails, because the same binding already exist, error nr. 80070002, but the error message is about other version, than in the Fuslogvw tool